# How to get best audio quality on music bot using discord.py?

Tags: python, ffmpeg, discord, discord.py

I've built a discord music bot in discord.py but for some reason, it doesn't play music in as high quality as Fredboat or Rythm(so I don't think voice chat's bitrate is the problem). I've tried a couple of things online.

The only thing that improved quality a little bit was downloading the song before playing it. But the quality was still far from anything like Fredboat's. It's also very impractical since downloading a 1h song takes a while and is space consuming.

I'm interested in how to fix this and the explanation for why this is happening.

This is the code we're currently using for the music bot:

````
from discord import FFmpegPCMAudio
import discord
from apscheduler.schedulers.asyncio import AsyncIOScheduler
from apscheduler.triggers.cron import CronTrigger
from discord.ext import commands, tasks
from youtubesearchpython import VideosSearch

class cmd_music(commands.Cog, name="music_commands"):

    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot
        self.music_queue = []
        self.scheduler = AsyncIOScheduler()
        self.scheduler.add_job(self.check_queue, CronTrigger(second="0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55"))
        self.scheduler.start()
    
    async def play_raw(self, voice_client):
        if not self.music_queue:
            return

        YDL_OPTIONS = {'format': 'bestaudio', 'noplaylist':'True'}
        FFMPEG_OPTIONS = {'before_options': '-reconnect 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect_delay_max 5', 'options': '-vn'}
        if not voice_client.is_playing():
            with YoutubeDL(YDL_OPTIONS) as ydl:
                info = ydl.extract_info(self.music_queue.pop(0), download=False)
            URL = info['formats'][0]['url']
            voice_client.play(FFmpegPCMAudio(URL, **FFMPEG_OPTIONS))
            voice_client.is_playing()

    async def check_queue(self):
        if not self.bot.voice_clients: return
        
        client = self.bot.voice_clients[0]
        if not client.is_playing():
            if self.music_queue:
                await self.play_raw(client)
           
        
    @commands.command(brief="join")
    async def join(self, ctx):
        await ctx.author.voice.channel.connect()

    @commands.command(brief="leave")
    async def leave(self, ctx):
        await ctx.voice_client.disconnect()
        self.music_queue = []

    @commands.command(brief="play")
    async def play(self, ctx, *name):
        url = VideosSearch(" ".join(name[:]), 1).result().get("result")[0].get("link")
        self.music_queue.append(url)
        await ctx.send("Now playing: " + url)

    @commands.command(brief="skip")
    async def skip(self, ctx):
        await ctx.send("Skipped current song")
        ctx.voice_client.stop()
        if self.music_queue:
            await self.play_raw(ctx.voice_client)```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anybody will ever come across this. My problem seemed to be that ffmpeg has a low audio streaming quality. Lavalink seems to provide a lot better quality.

I suggest viewing this youtube video playlist in which you are walked through every step of creating a very high quality music bot with discord.py and Lavalink:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tZPrkKT9QHc&list=PLYeOw6sTSy6ZIfraPiUsJWuxjqoL47U3u&index=1&ab_channel=CarberraTutorials

Answer (score 0):

I was also stuck in this quality issue. But I found a work around this.

You can also test this , I got same quality as that of streaming with no issues.

```
FFMPEG_OPTIONS = {'before_options': '-reconnect 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect_delay_max 5', 'options': '-vn'}

YDL_OPTIONS = {'format': 'bestaudio/best', 'noplaylist':'True'}

voice = get(client.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
with YoutubeDL(YDL_OPTIONS) as ydl:
    info = ydl.extract_info(url, download=False)
    I_URL = info['formats'][0]['url']
    source = await discord.FFmpegOpusAudio.from_probe(I_URL, **FFMPEG_OPTIONS)
    voice.play(source)
    voice.is_playing()
```